Seeking help diagnosing what is making unkillable zombies and/or crashing (freezing) my system
I have been experiencing crashes while gaming but I cannot tell which of Ubuntu, Hardware (GPU/CPU), Steam, or the game is the problem.
Steps to replicate the problem
This last crash was on a fresh boot with only Steam and the game running.
When the game freezes, I alt-tab to Steam and hit the stop button. I get the warning about losing progress, accept it and then nothing happens.
I open a terminal and run top. I see the PID for the game and use sudo kill -9 <pid> and nothing changes. I used screen capture to show what was happening (game running, steam, and the terminal window.
This full-on zombie process seems unkillable.
I log out. I log back in. The system hangs with a black screen and a white mouse pointer.
At this point, I'm forced to restart.
When the system came back up and I logged in, the screenshot had not been saved.
System specs
This is a new build. A Gigbyte board with 128GB RAM, i9-14900Fx32 CPU, Radeon R7900XTX GPU. Firmware version F9; Ubuntu 24.04.1. I saved up for over a year to buy this thing and now I have the weirdest bug with which I am seeking help diagnosing.
I chose the i9-14900Fx32 specifically because it was not known to have instability issues. I have not overclocked anything.
Additional info
When this crash happens it will take Friefox with it (Chrome is fine) with the same zombie process nature and the System Monitor will say it is ready but will not present a GUI nor close the phantom window (also a zombie).
Update
So after messing about with amdgpu in the hopes of fixing things, I made it all much worse and spent a day with a system that booted to a black screen.
When I was finally back in, the system froze just after I opened Firefox restored my tabs and started a YouTube video. I rebooted. Did not get the same problem from Chrome. Not been able to repeat the Firefox one either as that is what I am using to post this update.
After much Googling, I think I un-foobared the thing but I'm getting some very contradictory feedback from the terminal
lordmatt@vision:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo dpkg -P amdgpu && sudo dpkg -P amdgps-dkms
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove amdgpu which isn't installed
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove amdgps-dkms which isn't installed
lordmatt@vision:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:6.7.0.60103-1787201.22.04) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
lordmatt@vision:/var/lib/dpkg$ 

I have Schrodinger's amdgps-dkms it is both not installed and installed (pending post-install script) at the same time.
Update 2
After a lot of faff and crashes, I undid whatever amdgpu nonsense I had set in motion. Now I just need some way to profile the initial problem or find a fix in some way. AMDGPU is not, it seems, my answer.
Update 3
So original symptoms (system freezes) still exist. I can't tell if the GPU is the culprit. Freeze ups have happened when running only Firefox.
Update 4
Running amdgpu-install --uninstall freed up some room but was not a fix. Crashes are more frequent. Sound keeps playing though even when screen frozen and no keyboard or mouse input is getting through (not even capslock or numlock).
Update 5 - running some commands as requested
free --mega -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            132G        5.4G        125G        143M        2.9G        127G
Swap:           8.6G          0B        8.6G

cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
That returns 60. Is that good?
amdgpu
I tried to switch to amdgpu as ~I suspected that might be the problem. Oh, boy. The process hung; I watch Netflix; I go to bed; I get up and nothing has changed. It would get stuck setting up with the kernel. Most of my updates were me clawing back from that.
here is a screeny of that last build step just going hell-for-leather and getting nowhere.

lsmod | grep amdgpu
Nothing.
Update 4 is where I got off that train. (and got some system stability back). Along the way, I poked at a bunch of BIOS settings and learned a few hard lessons about not touching things I don't understand.
sudo hwinfo --gfxcard
sudo: hwinfo: command not found

I did a quick apt install and:
07: PCI 300.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: svHJ.+CDZH_5IkG4
  Parent ID: B35A.Sa24RQSJfUB
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:03:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "ATI VGA compatible controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x744c 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1eae "XFX Limited"
  SubDevice: pci 0x7901 
  Revision: 0xc8
  Memory Range: 0x40000000-0x4fffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x50000000-0x501fffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x5000-0x5fff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x50c00000-0x50cfffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 11 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d0000744Csv00001EAEsd00007901bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: amdgpu is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe amdgpu"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #12 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #7

sudo kill and sudo killall
I threw both of them at the zombies and they just ignored me. System Monitor also zombied during these times. It had "technically" started but there was no GUI element. One time, it was running and I tried to go from the graphs to the process list. It was not happening. System Monitor has stopped responding. Click the option to end it. Get the message again like I had not done anything.
As I say, unkillable zombies. I've never seen anything quite like it.
Here's a capture of process 12388 refusing to be killed. The "Stop" button on Steam had a similar failure to make anything happen. I rebooted.

linux-crashdump
I also installed linux-crashdump at some point so there may be some super verbose files around I could go dig up.
Update 6
Following advice from comments

I ran sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri mesa-opencl-icd mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
sudo systemctl stop gdm
sudo modprobe -r radeon
sudo modprobe amdgpu
sudo systemctl start gdm

Then sudo hwinfo --gfxcard gave me:
07: PCI 300.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)             
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: svHJ.+CDZH_5IkG4
  Parent ID: B35A.Sa24RQSJfUB
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:03:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "ATI VGA compatible controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1002 "ATI Technologies Inc"
  Device: pci 0x744c 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1eae "XFX Limited"
  SubDevice: pci 0x7901 
  Revision: 0xc8
  Driver: "amdgpu"
  Driver Modules: "amdgpu"
  Memory Range: 0x4800000000-0x4fffffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x4400000000-0x44001fffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x5000-0x5fff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x50c00000-0x50cfffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 205 (13478 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001002d0000744Csv00001EAEsd00007901bc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: amdgpu is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe amdgpu"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #12 (PCI bridge)

Primary display adapter: #7

Success?
After all that help, I was able to run a game that previously crashed within minutes.
I'm getting far fewer crashes and they no longer zombie the system.

Have you tried using sudo killall instead? So instead of using the PID you'd use the process name. Example: sudo killall firefox. This way, if there's more than one PID for the same process, it should kill all of them. Also, pgrep -l can help you search for running process names, so it essentially greps running processes for your search term and the -l option tells it to return or list the process name. Example to search for firefox related processes: pgrep -l fox.

Another option is using htop instead of top. htop is a bit more interactive and reveals more information, you can click to sort different columns, etc. Use the up and down arrow keys to highlight an offending process, press F9 (sometimes you need to press F9 twice) and then you can press 9 and then ENTER or use the down arrow key to select the 9 kill option and then press ENTER. This should show if other related processes of the same name still running (use F3 to search running processes, and then keep pressing F3 after typing a search term to page through each subsequent result).

Also, make sure you're using amdgpu instead of radeon. The amdgpu module is built in to the kernel even though non-kernel versions still exist. Run lsmod | grep amdgpu to see if it's loaded and sudo hwinfo --gfxcard should also tell you which one is running, either amdgpu or radeon. I think the amdgpu dkms version would be best as a separate question. If you do want it installed although it might not be much different in terms of performance, that usually involves running some of the commands manually to compile and see what errors pop up and then deal with those before trying again.

Sometimes I have a google chrome zombie process that slows down firefox.

What does your RAM and swap, swappiness, etc. look like? Run free --mega -h to list available ram and swap and cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness to list the swappiness value.

There was a bug that caused the swapfile or swap partition to fill up on intel systems and then performance would suffer. So it might help to check free --mega -h when you notice the problem to see if swap is full. iirc, setting /proc/sys/vm/watermark_boost_factor to zero fixes this: sudo sysctl vm.watermark_boost_factor=0 and if that does, then you can make that permanent by editing /etc/sysctl.conf and adding the following line to the end of the file: vm.watermark_boost_factor=0

I'm happy to take instructions on taking another crack at getting amdgpu to complete. I've seen content somewhere in my quest about some needed related stuff not getting added because the dependencies list dooduh missed them out.

Okay, save any unsaved work because this will log you out. Drop to a tty: CTRL+ALT+F5 and then sign in with your username and password and then run: sudo systemctl stop gdm and then run: sudo modprobe -r radeon and then run sudo modprobe amdgpu and then run sudo systemctl start gdm and it should take you back to the GUI but if not, then it should be on CTRL+ALT+F1 or CTRL+ALT+F2. Log back in and see if you encounter the issue. You should be using your GPU now. This is the amdgpu kernel driver that's included in the kernel.

Try running the hwinfo command again to verify that you are using the amdgpu and you should also be able to check if you go to the system settings and then click on "details" or similar where it should show what kind of Graphics is in use.

Also, make sure the following is installed: sudo apt update and sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri mesa-opencl-icd mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers If you want to try Xorg instead of Wayland, then also install: sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu

Yes, 60 is good. And with that much RAM, the used swap space will likely remain at zero. Also, amdgpu now shows that it's in use. If this fixes your issue, because now you should be actually using your GPU instead of the integrated intel graphics, then add amdgpu to your /etc/modules file or just run echo amdgpu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules so that amdgpu will automatically load when you boot up. Next time you reboot, however, run the hwinfo command to check and see if "amdgpu is active" as it should be.

If this does seem to fix the issue, then let me know and then I'll post it as an answer.

@mchid so far so good. I'll test drive for a while and report back. Thank you for your help; I truly appreciate your investment of time into my problem.

sudo hwinfo --gfxcard output shows amdgpu is not active (Update 5 above):

Driver Info #0:
  Driver Status: amdgpu is not active
  Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe amdgpu"


But you can use the default amdgpu kernel driver without installing the dkms version (it's built in to the regular kernel).

Before you begin, run the following comands to install the related mesa drivers, and also the amdgpu Xorg driver if you want to run X11 instead of Wayland:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri mesa-opencl-icd mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers

and optionally, if you want to use X11 instead of Wayland:
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu

Next, run the following command to enable the amdgpu kernel driver when you boot:
echo amdgpu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules

Finally, reboot and then run the following command to check the driver status:
sudo hwinfo --gfxcard | grep "Driver Status"

It should show the following

  Driver Status: amdgpu is active



UPDATE 1:
Okay, since amdgpu is blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d you can either delete the offending file if blacklist amdgpu is the only entry in the file
or you can edit the file and comment the line out so it reads #blacklist amdgpu instead of blacklist amdgpu
or you can use the following command to list any files that contain blacklist amdgpu:
grep -l "blacklist amdgpu" /etc/modprobe.d/*

and if any files are listed, then this command should automatically edit those files:
sudo sed -i 's/blacklist amdgpu/#&/' $(grep -l "blacklist amdgpu" /etc/modprobe.d/*)

Reboot to apply the changes.

You can also manually edit /etc/modules to add or remove kernel modules that will load when you boot the system.

I feel like I maybe did something wrong. amdgpu is in /etc/modules and in /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf but "amdgpu is not active". (After a reboot).

No, I fixed it. A long hard Google took me to /etc/modprobe.d a quick ls showed me a blacklist conf file for amdgpu, renamed it to a .bluh.old (something like that). Rebooted. No amdgpu is active.

@MatthewBrownakaLordMatt I added some more info based on that. If it's still not active after renaming the file, you can either (1) delete the file, or you can (2) edit the file and comment out the line that says blacklist amdgpu to show #blacklist amdgpu instead.

It is reporting as active now.  I cannot find words to say how grateful I am for your help and support. Thank you so very much. I really mean it. Thank you.

@MatthewBrownakaLordMatt It's always fun to give back to the community and it's like a puzzle. I experienced similar issues although different because my older card was using radeon instead of amdgpu after installation so I had to also disable radeon but that wasn't necessary here because it's a newer GPU.
